# django-cms yields "ImportError: cannot import name CacheKey"

Tags: django, heroku, pip, django-cms

I've recently updated my `django-cms` (from 2.3.4 to 2.4) and now I can no longer use ./manage.py (eg, with the `sqlall` statement). This is the output

```
(venv)felipe@:~/Projects/heroku$ ./manage.py sqlall
Executing configuration file dev.py
Executing configuration file django_cms.py
Executing configuration file common.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 231, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 67, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from moderatormodels import *
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/moderatormodels.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cms.models.pagemodel import Page
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 23, in <module>
    from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool
  File "/home/felipe/Projects/heroku/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menus/menu_pool.py", line 9, in <module>
    from menus.models import CacheKey
ImportError: cannot import name CacheKey
```

The app in the traceback is `django-menus`, which [django-cms relies](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.6/getting_started/tutorial.html#installing-and-configuring-django-cms-in-your-django-project) on. I've seen the same error being raised by cms_tags and others, though. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Looks like you have to reinstall the virtualenv: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-cms/v8FQaXk-PnM/4DIa1Ml90twJ

Comment: I've done it several times already. :(

Comment: Did you install `django-menus`?

Answer (score 1):

I've once again restarted my virtualenv, installing all the components needed, one at a time, and now it works. <del>magic, really</del>

Comment: I cant believe, this works. :D Thank you, a big thank you. Restarting virtualenv or activating a new one from console did work.